# Display Message When Boolean Change in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

```
void loop() {
    if(digitalRead(ACLED_Pin) == HIGH) {
       Serial.println("AC: ON");
    }else{
       Serial.println("AC: OFF");
    }
}
```

Hello, I have this code in my aduino, but i only want to display the messages when the boolean digitalRead(ACLED_Pin) change.
Now i have the following messages:

```
AC: OFF
AC: OFF
AC: OFF
AC: ON
AC: ON
AC: OFF
AC: OFF
```

And i want:

```
AC: OFF
AC: ON
AC: OFF
AC: ON
```

How Can i do this?

Comment: You need to store the previous state somewhere and check if the new state is different

Comment: UnholySheep: if only there was some text entry box somewhere where you could type in answers. That would be a valuable feature of SO, wouldn't it? :-) On a more serious note, I don't know *why* people insist on putting answers in comment boxes. That seems to me to be as problematic as putting comments in answer boxes. Not intending to give you a hard time, it's just I'm noticing this more and more.

Comment: @paxdiablo with only 3 close votes needed, the question can be gone before the lovely researched, formatted and tested answer can be finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to keep the last state and print when it changes (and on the first time regardless of previous state), something like:

```
void loop() {
    // Statics initialised only once, then they hold value.

    static bool first = true;
    static int last = HIGH;

     // Get current digital input value, act if first or changed.

    int curr = digitalRead(ACLED_Pin);
    if (first || (curr != last)) {
        Serial.println(curr ? "AC: ON" : "AC: OFF");

        // Changed (or first), clear first and remember new state.

        last = curr;
        first = false;
    }
}
```